# collectd is creating /home folder on my mac and I cannot remove it

Tags: filesystems, osx, root, macintosh

I posted this here instead of the apple site because this seems more like a *nix-ish issue and I think this site would be better suited for it.

I had installed collectd with graphite for monitoring my mac and I am seeing a /home foler that popped up.

I tried to remove it but I get this error.

```
rm: home/: Resource busy
```

There is nothing in the folder and if I run

```
lsof /home
```

I see no files that are opened. I don't know how to track down the problem and go about removing it from here, any ideas?

The output of `mount`:

```
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
```

Comment: Where did you see that appear?  Are you sure you're looking at the right directory (especially considering the `rm` command doesn't show the initial `/`)?  If it is in `/home`, could you double-check with `lsof /home/.`?

Comment: Yes I am in the right directory, I had `cd`'d to `/` so that is why I did `rm home/`. `lsof /home/` still gives me no output

Comment: Could `/home` be a mount point?  Look at `mount` output.

Comment: added output of `mount` to post

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `mount` output, `/home` is a mounting point.

You would need to `unmount` it if you were to delete the directory.

You should make sure that any process or service relying on it is disabled before you do it.  You'll probably need to remove the mount configuration which is hopefully in `/etc/fstab` which you can edit with `vifs`.

Comment: vifs command brings up an empty file (with a few notes as comments) If I do `sudo umount /home` it gives no errors but then somehow it is still mounted when I run `mount` again

Comment: `/home` appears to be automounted, so @deltaskelta needs to turn off the automounter or tell it not to touch `/home`, manually unmounting is not enough.